# c++ override operator and this

Tags: c++

I want to override the "="operator,but I have a problem,the class has a const member which I want to change when I use "=",I think deconstruct the object and construct a new object may be worked but "this" can not be change.so,would you help me?

Comment: I guess that simply not labeling the member const is not an option?  Why not?

Answer (score 1):

You may mark the member you want to change `mutable`. This is the purpose of the keyword.

Of course, you may be breaking the implicit contract to users of your class that `operator=` will not modify the class...

Comment: In fact,I just want to use "=" to copy the const member of a object to another.I want to know how to use deconstructor and constructor to make it.

Comment: @TonyWen: You can explicitly call the destructor and then use placement `new`, but that wouldn't be exception-safe.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the pimpl idiom.  For example:

```
class Foo_impl
{
public:
    Foo(int x, int y, int z)
        :x_(x), y_(y), z_(z)
    {}
    const int x_;
    int y_,z_;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int x, int y, int z)
        :impl_(new Foo_impl(x,y,z))
    {}    

    Foo & operator=(Foo rhs)
    {
        swap(rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    void swap(Foo & rhs)
    {
        std::swap(impl_, rhs.impl_);
    }

    // still need copy constructor
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Foo_impl> impl_;
};
```

I really don't see the point of this though.